# sed command to replace php.ini memory_limit

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

I have php.ini with memory_limit = 128M
I would like to replace this with sed command.

I had try this, and it does not work

```
sed -i '' 's/memory_limit\s*=\s*\d*M/memory_limit = 1024M/g' ~/Desktop/php.ini
```

any idea why?
I copy it to desktop so it does not tinker the original one before it actually working

Comment: Try removing your `sed -i 's/memory_limit\s*=.*/memory_limit=1024M/g' ~/Desktop/php.ini`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza what do you mean? removing everything? so what am I running?

Comment: I mean try removing your empty `''` and also change your regex after the `=`. Notice I put `memory_limit\s*=.*`

Answer (score 5):

I have modified your regex a little, also removed your empty single strings and it's working fine to me.

I changed this:

```
sed -i '' 's/memory_limit\s*=\s*\d*M/memory_limit = 1024M/g' ~/Desktop/php.ini
```

To this:

```
sed -i 's/memory_limit\s*=.*/memory_limit=1024M/g' ~/Desktop/php.ini
       Regex change here--^^
```

Console output

```
$ cat php.ini
asdfasd
memory_limit = 128M
fasd

$ sed -i 's/memory_limit\s*=.*/memory_limit=1024M/g' ~/php.ini

$ cat php.ini
asdfasd
memory_limit=1024M
fasd
```

Btw, my sed version is `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: And it is relevant to note that the question is tagged [tag:osx] and the `sed` delivered by default on Mac OS X is the BSD `sed` and the BSD `sed` does not behave the same as the GNU `sed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the very useful comment, didn't see that. I'll check later from my laptop

Answer (score 2):

The BSD `sed` on Mac OS X does not recognize `\s` as space and `\d` as digit even with the `-E` option:

```
$ echo 'memory_limit = 128M' | sed -E 's/memory_limit\s*=\s*\d*M/memory_limit = 1024M/g'
memory_limit = 128M
$                         # Oops - output is the same as the input!
```

I didn't manage to create an input string that is recognized by the `s///` you show, with or without the `-E` option (which surprises me a little; I tried a fair number of variations).  However, the substitution you require can be done portably and easily with:

```
$ echo 'memory_limit = 128M' |
> sed 's/memory_limit[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*M/memory_limit = 1024M/g'
memory_limit = 1024M
$
```

Fixing that so it does the in-place edit of the file without any backup (I hope you have the file under some sort of configuration management!) is a trivial combination of what I wrote and what you wrote.

If you use `-i.bak` (creating a backup; no space between `-i` and `.bak`), then the script will work with GNU `sed` as well as BSD `sed`. If you don't do the overwriting, then it will work with any POSIX-compliant `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work on `OSX`:

```
sed -Ei '' 's/(memory_limit = )[0-9]+M/\11024M/g' ~/Desktop/php.ini
```

`i` key for edit file in-place

`E` key for extended `regex`

`''` need to supply when no `.bak` (backup) specified

`s` substitute pattern with

`()`defining a group

`\1` group reference

`[0-9]+M` - any digit with `M` at the end

`g` - substitute all occurrences of the pattern

It's always good to save backup file:

```
sed -i .bak -E 's/(memory_limit = )[0-9]+M/\11024M/g' php.ini
```

This will save you a copy of `php.ini` before substitution to `php.ini.bak`